# image capturing is failing after one capture

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I'm working on my project which is a robot air hockey player;

in the project I'm using a Microsoft lifecam to identify the "ball" place.
that's working.

the problem is when I'm running the project in the main form -
if before entering the game I'm checking the camera (one pic)
that is the code inside the button:

```
 Capture capture = new Capture(0);
 Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr,byte>  temp = capture.QueryFrame();
 picture pic = new picture(temp);
 pic.ShowDialog();
```

and after the check I'm staring playing
the game is stopping giving me this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' 
occurred in Emgu.CV.dll
Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. 
This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

the image processing code is:

```
 class C_Camera
    {
        public Capture capWebCam = null;
        public bool binCapturingInProgress = false;
        public Image<Bgr, byte> imgOriginal;
        public Image<Gray, byte> imgProcessed;
        public ImageBox imageBox1 = new ImageBox();
        public TextBox textBox1;
        public List<PointF> centerList;
        CircleF[] circles;

        public void newCapture(bool b, List<PointF> centers)
        {
            centerList = centers;
            binCapturingInProgress = b;

            try
            {
                capWebCam = new Capture();
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException except)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(except.Message);
                return;
            }

            Application.Idle += processFrameAndUpdateGUI;//add process image function to the applicationlist in tasks
            binCapturingInProgress = true;
        }


        public void processFrameAndUpdateGUI(object sender, EventArgs arg)
        {
            imgOriginal = capWebCam.QueryFrame();
            if (imgOriginal == null) 
            {
                return;
            }
            imgProcessed = imgOriginal.InRange(new Bgr(0, 0, 150)/*min filter*/, new Bgr(80, 80, 256));
         //   imgProcessed = imgOriginal.InRange(new Bgr(0, 0, 175)/*min filter*/, new Bgr(100, 100, 256));

            imgProcessed = imgProcessed.SmoothGaussian(9);//9
            circles = imgProcessed.HoughCircles(new Gray(100), //canny threshhold
                                                          new Gray(50), //accumolator threshold
                                                          2,//size of image 
                                                          imgProcessed.Height / 4, //min size in pixels between centers of detected circles
                                                          15, //min radios
                                                          43)[0];//max radios and get circles from first channel
            foreach (CircleF circle in circles)
            {


                centerList.Add(circle.Center);
                //     circlesOfBalls.Add(circle);

                if (textBox1.Text != "") textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                textBox1.AppendText("ball position = x" + centerList[centerList.Count - 1].X +
                                    ", y = " + centerList[centerList.Count - 1].Y.ToString().PadLeft(4)
                                    + "centerList.Count= " + centerList.Count);

                // + ", radios = " + centerList[centerList.Count - 1].Radius.ToString("###,000").PadLeft(7))

                textBox1.ScrollToCaret();// scrolls the textBox to last line

                // draw a small green circle in the center
                CvInvoke.cvCircle(imgOriginal, // draw on the original image
                                  new Point((int)circle.Center.X, (int)circle.Center.Y),//center point of circle
                                  3, // radios of circle,
                                  new MCvScalar (0, 255, 0), // draw in green color
                                  -1, //indicates to fill the circle
                                  LINE_TYPE.CV_AA, //smoothes the pixels
                                  0);// no shift 

                //draw a red circle around the detected object
              //  if (imgOriginal.Data != null) 
                    imgOriginal.Draw(circle,    //current circle
                                new Bgr(Color.Red), // draw pure red
                                3);
            } // end of for each

           // if(imgOriginal.Data != null)
                imageBox1.Image = imgOriginal;
        }
```

i tried to search in google and here for an answer but couldn't find any.
if I'm not entering the camera check it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks off it you only capture the image once i see that you're suposed to capture a image when systems idle, but that might be too often or not often enough.

Try to add a DispatcherTimer and give it render priority and a frequency of 1000/60 (60 frames a second).

```
    DispatcherTimer UpdateTimer; 
    public Capture capWebCam = null;
    public bool binCapturingInProgress = false;
    public Image<Bgr, byte> imgOriginal;
    public Image<Gray, byte> imgProcessed;
    public ImageBox imageBox1 = new ImageBox();
    public TextBox textBox1;
    public List<PointF> centerList;
    CircleF[] circles;

    public void newCapture(bool b, List<PointF> centers)
    {
        centerList = centers;
        binCapturingInProgress = b;

        try
        {
            capWebCam = new Capture();
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException except)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(except.Message);
            return;
        }

        binCapturingInProgress = true;


        //Start the timer after the device is ready to be captured (this looks like a good place to do it)
        UpdateTimer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Render);
        UpdateTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000 / 60);
        UpdateTimer.Tick += processFrameAndUpdateGUI;
        UpdateTimer.Start();
    }

    private void processFrameAndUpdateGUI(object o, EventArgs e)
    {
       //Capture new image, render it and display it.

        imgOriginal = capWebCam.QueryFrame();
        if (imgOriginal == null) 
        {
            return;
        }
        imgProcessed = imgOriginal.InRange(new Bgr(0, 0, 150)/*min filter*/, new Bgr(80, 80, 256));
     //   imgProcessed = imgOriginal.InRange(new Bgr(0, 0, 175)/*min filter*/, new Bgr(100, 100, 256));

        imgProcessed = imgProcessed.SmoothGaussian(9);//9
        circles = imgProcessed.HoughCircles(new Gray(100), //canny threshhold
                                                      new Gray(50), //accumolator threshold
                                                      2,//size of image 
                                                      imgProcessed.Height / 4, //min size in pixels between centers of detected circles
                                                      15, //min radios
                                                      43)[0];//max radios and get circles from first channel
        foreach (CircleF circle in circles)
        {


            centerList.Add(circle.Center);
            //     circlesOfBalls.Add(circle);

            if (textBox1.Text != "") textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
            textBox1.AppendText("ball position = x" + centerList[centerList.Count - 1].X +
                                ", y = " + centerList[centerList.Count - 1].Y.ToString().PadLeft(4)
                                + "centerList.Count= " + centerList.Count);

            // + ", radios = " + centerList[centerList.Count - 1].Radius.ToString("###,000").PadLeft(7))

            textBox1.ScrollToCaret();// scrolls the textBox to last line

            // draw a small green circle in the center
            CvInvoke.cvCircle(imgOriginal, // draw on the original image
                              new Point((int)circle.Center.X, (int)circle.Center.Y),//center point of circle
                              3, // radios of circle,
                              new MCvScalar (0, 255, 0), // draw in green color
                              -1, //indicates to fill the circle
                              LINE_TYPE.CV_AA, //smoothes the pixels
                              0);// no shift 

            //draw a red circle around the detected object
          //  if (imgOriginal.Data != null) 
                imgOriginal.Draw(circle,    //current circle
                            new Bgr(Color.Red), // draw pure red
                            3);
        } // end of for each

       // if(imgOriginal.Data != null)
            imageBox1.Image = imgOriginal;
    }
```

Comment: hi thomas,
tnks for your help.

i tried to do what you told me, but unfortunatlly DispatcherTimer is available only in wpf.           

i couldnt find how to set timer priority.
so thats what i did:
 timer = new Timer();
            //time
            timer.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000 / 60).TotalMilliseconds);
            timer.Tick += processFrameAndUpdateGUI;
            timer.Start();

Comment: yes pretty much the same thing, i gueass the my idea on where the problem where and how to do it was correct. If you do it in forms you might want to use timer (can be found in the toolbox)

Comment: fixed it :)
all i needed to do is
capture.dispose();
in the main form
tnks